# Bibliography on Ethics in Science

Tags: ethics, practical-ethics

Can  you please recommend basic bibliography for an introduction to ethics in science ?

In particular, if it is clear that there is a project that looks interesting, but clearly it might be used for bad, then how can we analyze this kind of circumstances?

It is really common to listen arguments like:

- Worse things have been done,
- If I don't do it, someone else will do it,
- Whatever research output you get, it can be used for bad reasons as well.

I wonder how this arguments can/should be approached. So far I have not found researchers (in math oriented sciences) with enough background to give a solid approach to this kind of circumstances.

Any bibliographic suggestion is strongly appreciated.

**Particular context**: The question is not based on a particular outstanding case, but it is really easy to notice in the environment of computer science and applied mathematics that there is no emphasis in teaching ethics (at least in my environment).

This feeling has been growing among colleagues, and it has reached the case where one student asked in a research seminar if there has been any consideration of the ethical implications of a particular project. The was simply no answer.

Thus, this question is more focused on bibliography for persons that are not experts in philosophy, but rather on researchers that would like to get a feeling of the topic.

Comment: What sort of resources have you come across so far? Have you looked at Wikipedia's entry on [Research Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_ethics)? --Sharing a little more about the context here might help improve the chances of getting a great answer as well: what have you been reading that's made this an interesting or important problem in your study of philosophy?

Comment: @Joseph Weissman : I tried to be more specific. Please tell me if I should add more information.